# дефолтный лаунчер

Tags: android

Доброго дня други!
Возникла такая проблема: пишется приложение блокировщик экрана, плюс оно меняет фон рабочего стола. При этом каким-то образом оно сбивает настройки того, какое приложение является дефолтным лаунчером в системе. И если на телефоне больше одного - при нажати Хоум постоянно выскаквиает окно с выбором лаунчера. Вопрос(ы):

- почему может сбиваться эта настройка?
- можно ли как-то программно узнать кто был лаунчером и как-то его восстанавливать? (парвда пока еще и не ясно когда это надо делать)

Если что надо уточнить о приложении - расскажу, просто не знаю что сразу нужно уточнить.

Благодарю.

Comment: По вопросу "как узнать текущий лаунчер" уж еподсказали:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055762/how-to-get-the-package-name-of-current-launcher-in-android

Comment: Блин, а можно как-то по Enter не отпарвлять сообщение, а перевод строки делать???